# Macbook won't read disk

Tags: macbook, cd

I have a macbook that I erased the original iOS on to restart with Ubuntu but when I put in my home burned disk it doesn't read it correctly and makes loud clicking noises.

I burned it on a TDK CD-R80 700 MB CD from Windows 7 and even did the confirm to make sure it burned correctly.  It has never read CDs like that before, so it's weird.

Should I just make another CD?  Or is there something wrong with the Macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the CD with Windows 7 is not a CD.  Windows 7 does not fit on a CD, and neither does Ubuntu anymore.  You need a DVD.  Second, I wouldn't think that CD you got with Windows on it is writable, you may need to make another DVD.  Just burn the Ubuntu image to the DVD and you should be set.  If you don't have a DVD, you can do a crude hack that I came up with to install from USB really easily.  I'll put it here, but you will need some terminal knowledge.

1. Mount the EFI hidden partition.  `mkdir mnt ; sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 mnt`
2. Extract the Ubuntu iso.  You can use "The Unarchiver" from the Mac App Store.
3. Grab the file called `grubx64.efi` or similar.  It may also be named `bootx64.efi`.  Put this in `mnt/EFI/BOOT` and name it `BOOTX64.EFI`
4. You need to copy the iso image to a flash drive.  This will delete all data on the flash drive.  `dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/disk<usbdisk> bs=4m`.  You can find what disk is the flash drive by using `diskutil list`
5. When this finishes, take your drive out and put it back in.  It may take a while.  Using the rdisk variant of the device node may make it faster.
6. Restart the computer holding the option key.  Select `EFI Boot`
7. The EFI GRUB menu will load up if you did all this correctly, and you can boot Ubuntu.

Again, this is only needed if you want to do an installation from USB on your mac.  Even then I am sure there is another way, such as rEFIt.

Comment: I'm buying some blank DVDs today or tomorrow to burn Ubuntu to, and then install with that.  I was going to try your USB hack, but I can't find my extra USB right now.